# AngularJS 2 Dart get RouterLink Parameter

Tags: angularjs, angular, dart, angular2-routing

I want to create a details page in Angular and want to pass an entry id with the RouterLink. Is there a way to get the parameter in the url?

The URL looks like: `http://localhost:8080/details?date=13-09-2016`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `OnActivate`

```
  @override
  routerOnActivate(ComponentInstruction nextInstruction,
      ComponentInstruction prevInstruction) {
    String routeParamValue = nextInstruction.params['paramName'];
    String queryParamValue = nextInstruction.urlParams['paramName'];
  }
```

Comment: Where I have to put this?

Do I have to put this in the class part of the component?

Comment: To the component added by the router. You need to change `params` to `queryParams` for query parameters. `param` is for route parameters (`path: '/some/:paramName/other'`)

Comment: It doesn't work. It is even not called I already changed it to queryParams but it isn't even called. My Routing looks like this: 
`@RouteConfig(const [
  const Route(path: '/view', name: 'Home', component: SimpleKVComponent, useAsDefault: true),
  const Route(path: '/settings', name: 'Settings', component: SettingsComponent),
  const Route(path: '/details', name: 'Details', component: DetailsComponent)
])`

Comment: And it is called by this line:
`<td><a [routerLink]="['/Details', { date: history['link'] }]"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></a></td>`

Comment: Did you add `class DetailsComponent implements OnActivate {`?

Comment: Alright it is now called, thankyou but I still get an error:

`EXCEPTION: Class 'ComponentInstruction' has no instance getter 'queryParams'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'queryParams'
Receiver: Instance of 'ComponentInstruction'
Arguments: [](anonymous function) @ VM825:1
VM825:1 STACKTRACE:`

Comment: Try `urlParams` instead of `queryParams`

Comment: Sorry, mixed the name up with the TS router.

Answer (score 2):

Also [RouteParams](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/angular2/2.0.0-beta.20/angular2.router/RouteParams-class.html) can be used to get the parameter. You can injected it to your component:

```
@Component(...)
class MyDetailsComponent {
  final RouteParams _routeParams;
  MyDetailsComponent(this._routeParams){
    var date = _routeParams.get('date');
  }
}
```

You can find more details [here](https://angular.io/docs/dart/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html).